# How do I set the value of Asp.Net DropDownList using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a Asp.Net form:

```
<div id="my-fields">
   <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" />
   <asp:TextBox ID="Age" runat="server" />
   <asp:DropDownList ID="Dept" runat="server" required="true">
        <Items>
             <asp:ListItem Text="Human Resources" value="HR"/>
             <asp:ListItem Text="Information Technology" value="IT"/>
        </Items>
   </asp:DropDownList> 
</div>
```

When entering the text in "Name" TextBox, I am making a AJAX call to the Web API, which gets the values for Age and DropDownList fields and auto-populates these fields with the values.

This the jQuery to set the values from Web API to the fields:

```
 $("#my-fields input[id*='Name']").val(name);
 $("#my-fields input[id*='Age']").val(age);
 ***$("#my-fields select[id*='Dept']").val(dept);***
```

The problem is the value of "Dept" I am getting from Web API is, for eg: "Human Resources". And the the value for the ListItem is "HR". How do I auto-populate the drop-down fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `append` for that.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Dept" runat="server" required="true" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <Items>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Human Resources" Value="HR" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Information Technology" Value="IT" />
    </Items>
</asp:DropDownList>

<script>
    var $DeptDll = $('#Dept');

    //if you want to empty it first
    $DeptDll.empty();

    $DeptDll.append($('<option></option>').text('New Text Value').val('NTV'));
</script>
```

Comment: But this will add a new list item to the drop-down list? I want to set the text from the existing list items.

Comment: Something like this? `$DeptDll.find('option[value=HR]').text('Human Resources 1');`